# Custom sorting of dataframe by column with duplicates

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I wanted to ask for help, because I am having difficulties ordering my table, because the column for the table to be ordered has duplicates (`coltoorder`). This is a tiny part of my table. The desired order is custom, roughly speaking, it is based on the order of the first column, except for the first value (887).

```
text<-"col1 col2 col3 coltoorder
895     2    1374  887
888     2      14  887
1018    3    1065  895
896     2     307  895
889     2       4  888
891     2       8  888
1055    2     971 1018
926     3     241  896
1021    2      87 1018
897     2      64  896"
mytable<-read.table(text=text, header = T)
mytable
```

desired order

```
myindex<-c(887,895,888,1018,896) # equivalent to
myindex2<-c(887,887,895,895,888,888,1018,1018,896,896)
```

some failed attemps

```
try1<-mytable[match(myindex, mytable$coltoorder),]
try2<-mytable[match(myindex2, mytable$coltoorder),]
try3<-mytable[mytable$coltoorder %in% myindex,]
try3<-mytable[myindex %in% mytable$coltoorder,]
try4<-mytable[myindex2 %in% mytable$coltoorder,]
rownames(mytable) <- mytable$coltoorder # error
```

Comment: The description of the sort order you want is not very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `coltoorder` should be treated categorically, not numerically. All factors have an order of their levels, so we'll convert to a factor where the levels are ordered according to `myindex`. Then this ordering is "baked in" to the column and we can use `order` normally on it.

```
mytable$coltoorder = factor(mytable$coltoorder, levels = myindex)
mytable[order(mytable$coltoorder), ]
#     col1 col2 col3 coltoorder
# 8    895    2 1374        887
# 1    888    2   14        887
# 131 1018    3 1065        895
# 9    896    2  307        895
# 2    889    2    4        888
# 4    891    2    8        888
# 168 1055    2  971       1018
# 134 1021    2   87       1018
# 39   926    3  241        896
# 10   897    2   64        896
```

Do be careful - this column is now a `factor` not a `numeric`. If you want to recover the numeric values from a factor, you need to convert via character: `original_values = as.numeric(as.character(mytable$coltoorder))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your data sample suggests that your desired sort order is equivalent to the first appearance in column `coltoorder`.

*If this is true*, the function `fct_inorder()` from Hadley Wickham's `forcats` package may be particular helpful here:

```
mytable$coltoorder <- forcats::fct_inorder(as.character(mytable$coltoorder))
mytable[order(mytable$coltoorder), ]
   col1 col2 col3 coltoorder
1   895    2 1374        887
2   888    2   14        887
3  1018    3 1065        895
4   896    2  307        895
5   889    2    4        888
6   891    2    8        888
7  1055    2  971       1018
9  1021    2   87       1018
8   926    3  241        896
10  897    2   64        896
```

`fct_inorder()` reorders factors levels by first appearance. So, there is no need to create a separate `myindex` vector.

However, the caveats from [Gregor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45380622/3817004) apply as well.